# Programmatically Configure Auditing in Secure Store Service and Site Collection

Tags: object-model, auditing, secure-store

For Auditing to be enabled, I have read that, it has to be turned on at the Secure Store Service. Also, it needs to be configured at the Site Collection Level. So, is it possible to check programmatically(through Object Model and not Power Shell) whether this setting is turned on in Secure Store Service? If so, can you please provide the code? Also, how can we configure programmatically what information needs to be captured as part of the Audit at the Site Collection level. Please provide the code.